# Prove that $X^6 - 10X^3 +8$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that $X^6 - 10X^3 +8$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It's enough to show that the polynomial is irreducible modulo $11$.

Comment: or even to reduce it modulo 3

Comment: @akech: over $\mathbb{F}_3$ it factors as $(x^2-x-1)^3$. That (standalone) looks pretty inconclusive to me. On the other hand, over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ it splits as $(x^3-3)(x^3+6)$ and it has no rational root by the rational root theorem.

Comment: The strategy remains to reduce it mod an appropriate prime provided the leading coefficient is not reduced to zero and then checking to see if it is irreducible there. I am sorry my suggested prime didn't work. I think the change of variables to look at the resultant quadratic is also a possibility to explore.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It is enough to show that your polynomial is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5+\sqrt{17}}$.

Obviously $p(x)=x^2-10x+8$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=5+\sqrt{17}$, whose conjugate is $\overline{\alpha}=5-\sqrt{17}$, and we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. If we set $\beta=\alpha^{1/3}$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$ is either $1$ or $3$, depending on $x^3-\alpha$ being irreducible or not over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. A third-degree polynomial is irreducible iff it has no linear factors, so the problem boils down to checking if $5+\sqrt{17}$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})$. That cannot happen, for many reasons. For instance, in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ we have that $17$ is a quadratic residue (since $17\equiv 4$) but $5\pm 2$ is not a cubic residue, since: 
$$(5\pm 2)^{\frac{13-1}{3}}\not\equiv 1\pmod{13}.$$
As an alternative, we may check that the factorizations of $p(x)=x^6-10x^3+8$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ are not compatible, so the conclusion is the same as above: $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Jack, as to your comment comparing $3$ and $13,$ there is a very nice article by Lenstra and Stevenhagen about Chebotarev Density and the easier Frobenius Density. One thing they do is point out that inconsistent factoring partitions for different primes means irreducible.  http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/chebotarev.pdf   Bottom page 31

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Actually, that is the real problem. I try so show that $ X^6-10 X^3+8$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5+\sqrt{17}}$. Why  my question is put on hold?

Comment: @AlexBa: probably because it lacks some real effort. Anyway, I provided more details.